# android- convert arraylist to one string in custom format

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist

i have data in sqlit database so i use it to store categoreis and items
and i get it in arraylist like this:

```
    public ArrayList showDataItems(String id_cate){
    ArrayList<Items>  arrayListItems = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cr  = db.rawQuery("select * from items where id_cate = "+id_cate,null);

    cr.moveToFirst();

    while (cr.isAfterLast() == false){
        String item_id = cr.getString(0);
        String ItemName = cr.getString(1);
        String Item_quantity = cr.getString(2);
        String icon = cr.getString(3);
        int isDone  = Integer.parseInt(cr.getString(5));

        arrayListItems.add(new Items(item_id,ItemName,Item_quantity,R.drawable.shopicon,icon,isDone));
        cr.moveToNext();
    }
    return  arrayListItems;
}
```

so i need to get this data and convert it to string and share it to other application like whatsapp  in custom format for example :

1- first one * 
 2- second one *
3-....

so i use this code for send data

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
         intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"hello world");
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"send items i need all 
        data here"));
```

so we can use  string builder or some thing to get data in one string 
 please help me!

Comment: What data you want to send to whatsapp ?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, there is a StringBuilder class who can help formatting strings.
[Here are the java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

From StringBuilder, see the **append(..)** method. For your example:

```
    int size = list.size();
    for(int i = 0; i< size-1;i++){
        stringBuilder.append(i+1).append("- ").append(list.get(i)).append('\n');
    }
    stringBuilder.append(size).append("- ").append(list.get(size-1));
```

The last call to append is different from the firstone by not appending the end line